# Can someone help me understand the logic of this?

Tags: python

```
result = 0
for value in [14, 1, 33, 9, 25, 17]:
    result = result + 1
print(result)
```

So the result is 6. But I cant seem to understand why? Like what is actually going on logically to get to the output "6"?

Comment: You are counting the number of items...

Comment: just print `len([14, 1, 33, 9, 25, 17])`

Comment: What exactly did you expect to happen? What's *your* interpretation of the logic, and how does the behaviour you're observing differ from that?

Comment: @pieters I see that now. I did not before though, hence why I was asking...

Answer (score 1):

It basically defines a variable `result` that has 0 assigned to it, then in a for loop, it loops through the list `[14, 1, 33, 9, 25, 17]` which has 6 items in it, on each iteration `value` is assigned the next valu in the list and incrementing `result` after 6 iterations, `result` is incremented 6 times

Comment: Oh ok. The result+1 part is what was confusing me. I get it now, it's adding 1 to the variable for each item until it gets the the end and then prints it. Thank you!